# Why <router-link> and routers.js does not work in vue.js project?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vue-router

I am new to the vue.js and I am making a project to practice. I am using Vue 2. I have two pages. One page lists some blog posts' title and body like this:
[example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGDHU.png)

I am fetching these datas from here: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts. Titles should be clickable and when user clicks a post's title, it should direct to the other page which displays only the title and body of the clicked post.

here below is my app.vue file:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <PostItem/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import PostItem from './components/PostItem.vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    PostItem
}
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

here is my PostItem component which lists posts's titles and bodies:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
            <router-link v-bind:to="'/post/' + post.id "><h1>{{post.title}}</h1></router-link>
            <p>{{post.body}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>    
</template>

<script>
export default{
    name:'PostItem',
    data(){
        return{
            posts:[]
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => this.posts = data)
        .catch(err => console.log(err.message))
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

and here is my singlePost component which only displays the title and the body of clicked post:

```
<template>
    <div id="single-post">
        <h1>{{blog.title}}</h1>
        <p>{{blog.body}}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        data(){
            return {
                id: this.$route.params.id,
                post:{}
            }
        },
        created(){
            this.$http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + this.id).then(function(data){
                this.post = data.body;
            });
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
#single-post{
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
```

I am using route parameters to get id parameter from the URL. Here below is my router.js :

```
import PostItem from './components/PostItem.vue';
import singlePost from'./components/singlePost.vue';

export default[
    {path:'/', component: PostItem},
    {path:'/post/:id', component: singlePost}
]
```

Problem is that when I run the project, it displays titles and bodies of the posts but I can't click the titles even though I covered titles with router-link tag in PostItem component. What is the problem? Moreover, even though I adjust the path as '/' for PostItem component in routers.js file, it doesn't work. I can see PostItem screen whatever I write to the path like this:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxFu1.png)

What might be the problem?

here below jsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  }
}
```

structure of the project:
[structure of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPGht.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your `router.js` just exports an array of route definitions, so it looks like you haven't actually setup Vue Router properly.

Also, it looks like your `App.vue` component is missing `router-view`, which is required to render the current route.

Finally, your `singlePost.vue` component has several issues:

1. It uses `this.$http`, which does not exist in your code. That should just be `fetch`, which is what your other API call uses.
2. It uses a regular function to assign component data, but the regular function's `this` is not the component instance. Use an arrow function instead to capture the correct context.
3. It copies the `body` property from the API response into `this.post`, but the template assumes `post` is the entire response. Instead of copying just the `body`, copy the entire object into `this.post`.
4. The template uses a nonexistent `blog` property. That should probably be `post`.

### Solution

In `router.js`, export the result of [`createRouter()`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#createrouter). This result is a Vue plugin that sets up the components for `router-link` and `router-view`:

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

export default createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [/* your route definitions here */],
})
```

And in `main.js`, pass that Vue plugin instance to [`app.use()`](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-use):

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

createApp(App)
  .use(router) 
  .mount('#app')
```

In `App.vue`, insert `router-view` into the template (and remove everything else):

```html
<template>
  <main>
    <router-view />
  </main>
</template>
```

In `singlePost.vue`:

```html
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      id: this.$route.params.id,
      post: {},
    }
  },
  created() {
    1️⃣
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + this.id)
      .then(resp => resp.json())

      2️⃣
      .then(data => {

        3️⃣
        this.post = data
      })
  },
}
</script>

<template>
  <div id="single-post">
           4️⃣
    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ post.body }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-render-route?file=src%2Frouter.js,src%2Fmain.js,src%2FApp.vue)